# Programmatically connect to remote MongoDB with SSH

Tags: mongodb, ssh, cmd

I need to use terminal to connect to MongoDB. I have almost precisely same issue as [this StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527761/how-to-connect-to-remote-mongodb-with-authentication-and-ssh-tunneling) question.
In my case I can correctly use Robo3T to connect. As well as use command
`mongo --host 111.111.111.111 --port 111 --authenticationDatabase DB --username USER --password PASS` **locally**. With same command executed remotely I receive following error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I wanted to precisely recreate my Robo3T connection setup to see if SSH tunnel solves my issue